# External link menu item with tell or callto

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item

I want to have a menu item in joomla-3x so that when a user taps on it, automatically opens the Phone dial app on smart phones. I found the following structure on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23486695/963543):

```
<a href="tel:1234567">Call 123-4567</a>
<a href="callto:1234567">Call 123-4567</a>
```

But when I fill the link field's value with `tel:1234567`, I get the `Save not permitted.` error.

Is it possible to have such menu item without any core hacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work just fine. You do however need to ensure you set the **Menu Item Type** to **External URL**.

---

See the screenshots below:

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: My Joomla version I am using is 3.5.1. I think may this is problem I get the aforementioned error. Please tell me what your Joomla version is.

Comment: Joomla 3.5.1 is old. Please update to 3.6.2 as this issue was most likely fixed after your current version.

Comment: I am a bit afraid of extension conflict with the new version. But I will update soon. Thanks in advance @Lodder.

Comment: In which case take a backup of your site first. Then update Joomla and all 3rd party extensions too